# IronPython getting function code as string at runtime

Tags: python, ironpython, introspection

i am implementing a function framework in python to be accessed from
C#.

As a requirement, i have to provide a "string representation" of the function at runtime.

Is there a way to get the code definition of a function as a string? something
like:

```
def sum(a,b): 
    return a + b

def ToString(sum):
    # would return "def sum(a,b): return a+b" or something alike.
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does the representation actually have to indicate what the source code of the function is? What are you going to do with the representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`inspect.getsource()`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource).  Note that it will only work if the source file is accessible, so it won't work in the interactive console.